# Getting the editor content - Ext-Js html editor

Tags: javascript, extjs, html-editor

I'm new to Ext-Js and I've gotten a html editor  with some plugins from github, now I've got a  button on the editor that is supposed to pop an alert box with the contents of the text area.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

     var top = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        frame:true,
        title:          'HtmlEditor plugins',
        bodyStyle:      'padding:5px 5px 0',
        //width:          300,
        fieldDefaults: {
            labelAlign:     'top',
            msgTarget:      'side'
        },

        items: [{
            xtype:          'htmleditor',
            fieldLabel:     'Text editor',
            height:         300,
            plugins: [
                Ext.create('Ext.ux.form.plugin.HtmlEditor',{
                    enableAll:  true
                    ,enableMultipleToolbars: true
                })
            ],
            anchor:         '100%'
        }],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Save'
        },{
            text: 'Cancel'
        }]
    });

    top.render(document.body);

});
```

I know I'm supposed to add

```
handler:function(){alert(someextjscodehere)}
```

but I have no idea what function returns it, nor can I find it on google...

Comment: Are you sure you need the plugin? The base HtmlEditor is present in Ext, the plugin just add a few features.

Comment: yes, I'm sure. The original editor doesn't have the table, undo, redo...functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`getValue`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor-method-getValue) method of the editor to retrieve its content.

[`handler`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-handler) is an option of the button.

You'll need a reference to the editor in the handler, to get its content. You can get it from the form with the [`findField`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-findField) method, or with a [component query](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-down).

Here's how to update your code to alert the content of the editor when clicking the save button. I've added a second save button to show you the component query method. I've tested it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/DFx2S/).

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

    var top = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        frame:true,
        title:          'HtmlEditor plugins',
        bodyStyle:      'padding:5px 5px 0',
        //width:          300,
        fieldDefaults: {
            labelAlign:     'top',
            msgTarget:      'side'
        },

        items: [{
            xtype:          'htmleditor',
            name: 'htmlContent', // add a name to retrieve the field without ambiguity
            fieldLabel:     'Text editor',
            height:         300,
            /*            plugins: [
                    Ext.create('Ext.ux.form.plugin.HtmlEditor',{
                        enableAll:  true
                        ,enableMultipleToolbars: true
                    })
                ],
    */            anchor:         '100%'
        }],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Save'
            ,handler: function() {
                var editor = top.getForm().findField('htmlContent');
                alert(editor.getValue());
            }
        },{
            text: 'Save 2'
            ,handler: function() {
                // You can grab the editor with a component query too
                var editor = top.down('htmleditor');
                alert(editor.getValue());
            }
        },{
            text: 'Cancel'
        }]
    });

    top.render(document.body);

});
```

Comment: Oops. Of course, you can reenable your plugin, I've commented it out in order to make your code work in the jsFiddle ^^ Have fun with your learning of Ext!